# Joomla 2.5 - RSForm! PRO Email Submission Based on User

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

I have this scenario in mind:
I would like to implement the form in such a way that it sends the form to different email addresses based on User.

Scenario:

User A sends Form X to Email Address 1

User B sends Form X to Email Address 2

User C sends Form X to Email Address 3

I can used {global:fullname} to capture the logged in user. Currently, I have a set of list (dropdown) for users to choose the email address to send to. It does not look professional and I intend to change the workflow.

Any help or assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

RSForm PRO is a very powerful forum builder. It allows you to add code to your forms to manipulate the behavior of the form.

In this post http://www.itoctopus.com/how-to-easily-create-notification-emails-for-form-submissions-in-rsform , we explain how to create a notification email. You will need to take the code in the post, and then, based on the logged in user, you modify the `$mailer->addRecipient('[our-client-email]');` code in order to send the email to the appropriate user. Of course, you will need to make some other minor changes, but you get the point.

Hope this helps!